# Как снять либо установить галочку у главного Checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Есть неизвестное кол-во checkbox. Первый checkbox с помощью функции `check_all()`, ставит галочки на все остальные чекбоксы.

Как сделать следующее: если все `id="user_id"` выделены галочками, то на `id="all"` тоже ставилась галочка, если хоть одну галочку снять, то с `id="all"` снимается галочка.

Т. е. если нажаты все чекбоксы, на первом тоже ставится галочка, если хоть одна снята, то на первом тоже снимается галочка.

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="check_all();" id="all" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />

<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_1" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_2" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_20" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_30" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_45" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$("#all").click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
$("checkItem").click(function() {
  if ($('.abc:checked').length == $('.abc').length) {
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$('[id^="user_"]').click(function() {
  if ($('[id^="user_"]:checked').length == $('[id^="user_"]').length) {
    $("#all").prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $("#all").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="all" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />

<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_1" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_2" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_20" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_30" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="user_id_45" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку с jQuery здесь уже есть, то моё решение без её использования:

> Также стоит обратить внимание на то, что `IE10` не поддерживает функции `forEach` и `addEventListener`. Поэтому моё решение без их использования. В IE можно использовать `attachEvent` вместо `addEventListener`.

```js
var users = document.getElementById('users')
    usersInputs = users.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    allCheckbox = document.getElementById('all');

users.onclick = function(e)
{
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input')
    {
        var checked = true;

        for(var i = usersInputs.length; i--;)
            if(!usersInputs[i].checked)
            {
                checked = false;
                break;
            }

        allCheckbox.checked = checked ? true : false;
    }
};

function check_all()
{
    for(var i = usersInputs.length; i--;)
        usersInputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked)check_all()" id="all" name="" value="1" checked="checked" />check all</label>
<hr>
<div id="users">
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="user_id_1" name="" value="1" checked="checked"/>user_id_1</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="user_id_2" name="" value="1" checked="checked"/>user_id_2</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="user_id_20" name="" value="1" checked="checked"/>user_id_20</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="user_id_30" name="" value="1" checked="checked"/>user_id_30</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="user_id_45" name="" value="1" checked="checked"/>user_id_45</label>
</div>
```